# calling method using web3j returns null

Tags: web3j

while calling an contract method using web3j returns null.Deployed in Remix ,getting response and deployed in geth console ,got response.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Like contracts used, how do you call the contract methods, error messages, etc.

Answer (score -1):

May be you forget add .send() in the end of function? It was a typical mistake for me.